# output or value of gettype ?? in .NET

Tags: vb.net

i just want to ask the output value of GetType... i'm studying .net right now and testing some conditions, right now i'm reading the value inside the textbox and checking its type please see my sample code...i really need some help regarding this condition, i always get the message of "wrong value"

```
                        TextBox2.Text = file.ReadLine()
                        schar = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
                        If schar.Substring(0, 5).GetType() Is GetType(Integer) Then
                            'MessageBox.Show((schar.Substring(0, 5)))
                            MessageBox.Show("True  1")
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("wrong type.")
                            Exit Do
                        End If
```

Comment: `GetType` doesn't do what you seem to thing it does. `schar.Substring(0, 5)` is a String and so `GetType()` will return System.String.

Comment: Get Type return an internal enum and can be cast to an interger.  Your code is comparing a string array type with an integer type.

Comment: a textbox's text is always and forever `String`.  You probably want to parse it to see if it is Int32

Comment: `Substring` returns a new string. The type of string is `String` and will never be equal to the type of `Integer`. If you want to check if a string is an integer, use `Integer.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out if a String can be converted to an Integer, you can use Integer.TryParse

```
schar = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
Dim number As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(schar.Substring(0, 5), number) Then
    MessageBox.Show("True  1")
    'number contains the Integer
Else
    MessageBox.Show("wrong type.")
End If
```